# I developed an auto complete field and i want to save that field in controller.how can i do that?

Tags: visualforce

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class AppreciationController {

    public List<Appreciation__c> EpmList{get; set;}
    ApexPages.StandardController sc;
    public Appreciation__c objAppreciation{get;set;}
    public String strThumbs{get;set;}

    public AppreciationController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        sc=controller;
        EpmList = new List<Appreciation__c>();
        objAppreciation=new Appreciation__c();
        EpmList = [Select Description__c,Employee__c, Project__c, Type__c from Appreciation__c]; 
        strThumbs='';
    }

    public PageReference ThumbsUpAction()
    {
        objAppreciation.Type__c='Thumbs Up';
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference ThumbsDownAction()
    {
        objAppreciation.Type__c='Thumbs Down';
        return null;
    }

    public void SaveAppreciation()
    {
        insert objAppreciation;
    }


}
```

Visualforce pages:

```
<apex:page standardController="Appreciation__c" extensions="AppreciationController" docType="HTML-5.0" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() 
            {
                var availableTags = ["ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp"];
                $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({source: availableTags}); 
            });
        </script>
<apex:form > 
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!SaveAppreciation}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Employee Appreciation" columns="1" collapsible="false">
        <div class="ui-widget">
              <label for="tags">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   Employee    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </label>
              <input id="tags"/>
        </div>


        <apex:inputfield value="{!objAppreciation.Project__c}"/>
        <apex:inputfield value="{!objAppreciation.Description__c}"/>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:commandlink action="{!ThumbsUpAction}" style="float:center;" rerender="Panel1" >
                <apex:image id="ThumbsUpImage" value="{!$Resource.ThumbsUp}" width="50" height="50"/>
            </apex:commandlink>

            <apex:commandlink action="{!ThumbsDownAction}" style="float:center;" rerender="Panel1">
                <apex:image id="ThumbsDownImage" value="{!$Resource.ThumbsDown}" width="50" height="50"/>
            </apex:commandlink>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

       <apex:outputPanel id="Panel1">
           <apex:outputField value="{!objAppreciation.Type__c}"/>
       </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

UPDATE - it's working...

```
j$(document).ready(function(){
              j$(".apexemployeeautocomplete").autocomplete({
                  source : apexEmployeeList
           });  
            j$("#button").click(function(){
              alert('somevalue');
             // var obj = document.getElementById("{!$Component.form.panel.apexemployeeautocomplete}");
              alert(obj);
              });   

          });
```

Comment: Sanjeev, you've posted a lot of code but haven't really explained what your questions is and where (in your code) you think you need some help. Could you provide more information on what you're expecting us to help with ?

Comment: hi Samuel I was looking for how to save auto complete field in controller, Anyway got this solution. thanks for your help...

Comment: Which one is the solution ? Please mark it as the solution so that others can also get an idea. :P

Answer (score 4):

In your controller, introduce
 `public String autoCompleteText {get;set;}`
In the VF page, instead of `<input id="tags"/>` 
use
`<apex:inputText id="tags" value="{!autoCompleteText}" />`

For jQuery selector `$("#tags")` won't work here. So replace it with `$("id$=['tags']")`

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change to your code. it should work.

```
j$(document).ready(function(){
              j$(".apexemployeeautocomplete").autocomplete({
                  source : apexEmployeeList
           });  
            j$("#button").click(function(){
              alert('somevalue');
             // var obj = document.getElementById("{!$Component.form.panel.apexemployeeautocomplete}");
              alert(obj);
              });   

          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi sanjeev create custom component for controller and call that component into the another visualforce page.